# tidy_eval issue with facet_grid() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to plot each of "X1 by grpA", "X2 by grpA", "X3 by grpB", "X1 by grpB", "X2 by grpB", and "x3 by grpB" using ggplot2::ggplot() in conjunction with a for loop.

So far, I can get it to almost work, but the argument for the column of the grouping variable in the facet_grid() function does not resolve correctly when I try to use tidy_eval properties. It does work, however, when I type the column name explicitly, but of course, having to type the name explicitly would make it so I would not be able to dynamically change the grouping variable.

I provide the following data-set returned by the following code snippet to give context to my question:

```
set.seed(1)
dfr <- tibble(x1 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:7]),
             x2 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:7]),
             x3 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:7]),
             grpA = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2")),
             grpB = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.6, 0.4) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2"))
             )

head(df)
```

I also provide a function that creates the plotting data I need to make the grouped plots. It accepts strings as arguments for the parameters 'groupvar' and 'mainvar':

```
plot_data_prepr <- function(dat, groupvar, mainvar){
  
  groupvar <- sym(groupvar)
  mainvar <- sym(mainvar)
  
  plot_data <- dat %>% 
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>% 
    count(!!mainvar, .drop = F) %>% drop_na() %>% 
    mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         pct2 = ifelse(n == 0, 0.005, n/sum(n)),
         grp_tot = sum(n),
         pct_lab = paste0(format(pct*100, digits = 1),'%'),
         pct_pos = pct2 + .02)
  
  return(plot_data)
}
```

here is normal usage of the function:

```
plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr, groupvar = "grpA", mainvar = "x1")
```

Now I share my for loop that fails when I try to use tidy_eval in the facet_grid() function in the context of ggplot(); the returned error = "Error in !sgvar : invalid argument type"

"FAILING EXAMPLE:"

```
for (i in seq_along(names(dfr)[1:3])){
  mvar <- names(dfr)[i]
  print(mvar)
  
  gvar <- names(dfr[4])
  print(gvar)
  
  smvar <- sym(mvar)
  sgvar <- sym(gvar)
  
  plot <- ggplot(data=plot_data_prepr(dfr, gvar, mvar),
         mapping = aes(x=!!smvar, y = pct2, fill = !!smvar)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    ylim(0,1) +
    geom_text(aes(x=!!smvar, label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ !!sgvar) +
    ggtitle(paste0(mvar," by ",gvar))

  print(plot)
  
}
```

When I run the loop by explicitly typing `grpA` in place of `!!sgvar` in the facet_grid() function, it works for some reason:

"FUNCTIONING BUT NOT WHAT I WANT EXAMPLE:"

```
for (i in seq_along(names(dfr)[1:3])){
  mvar <- names(dfr)[i]
  print(mvar)
  
  gvar <- names(dfr[4])
  print(gvar)
  
  smvar <- sym(mvar)
  sgvar <- sym(gvar)
  
  plot <- ggplot(data=plot_data_prepr(dfr, gvar, mvar),
         mapping = aes(x=!!smvar, y = pct2, fill = !!smvar)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    ylim(0,1) +
    geom_text(aes(x=!!smvar, label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ grpA) +
    ggtitle(paste0(mvar," by ",gvar))

  print(plot)
  
}
```

Of course, if I wanted to loop through a set of grouping variables, then needing to explicitly type each one would not allow for looping.  Could someone explain why my code with the 'bang bang' operator inside facet_gric() doesn't work properly in the 'FAILING EXAMPLE' and also suggest how to remedy this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the function you posted is missing it's construction and formals (arguments), so I cannot reproduce what you're trying to show. That said, have your tried `facet_grid(cols = vars(!!grpA))`?

Comment: Object `mvars` is also missing when we try to reproduce your code. Something I'm not understanding (and maybe it comes from the fact that I cannot reproduce your example) is why you are saying you are having problems with `facet_grid` if what you change in your examples is `ggtitle`. Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: thanks so much for trying to help me -- and sincere apologies for providing code with so many errors.  I fixed it now -- and so my question should hopefully make sense.  Though I believe @Allan Cameron below was able to solve my problem with the as.formula() function inside the facet_grid() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to piece together exactly what you're looking for, since your example code has errors, unassigned variable names and pieces of code missing. However, I think you're wanting the loop to print all of the pairs of grouping variables and main variables by cycling through the names of your data frame.

So that there is no dubiety, here is a full reprex:

**Load packages and create reproducible data:**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(x1 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = TRUE)),
             x2 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = TRUE)),
             x3 = factor(sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = TRUE)),
             grpA = factor(sample(c("grp1", "grp2"), 50, 
                                  prob = c(0.3, 0.7), replace=TRUE)),
             grpB = factor(sample(c("grp1", "grp2"), 50, 
                                  prob = c(0.6, 0.4), replace=TRUE)))
```

**Define data preparation function**

```
plot_data_prepr <- function(dat, groupvar, mainvar)
{
  groupvar <- sym(groupvar)
  mainvar <- sym(mainvar)
  
  plot_data <- dat %>% 
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>% 
    count(!!mainvar, .drop = F) %>% tidyr::drop_na() %>% 
    mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
           pct2 = ifelse(n == 0, 0.005, n/sum(n)),
           grp_tot = sum(n),
           pct_lab = paste0(format(pct*100, digits = 1),'%'),
           pct_pos = pct2 + .02)
  
  return(plot_data)
}
```

**Loop to create all 6 plots**

```
for(gvar in names(df)[4:5]){
  for(mvar in names(df)[1:3])
  {
    print(ggplot(plot_data_prepr(df, gvar, mvar),
                 aes(x = !!sym(mvar), y = pct2, fill = !!sym(mvar))) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
      ylim(0,1) +
      geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar))) +
      ggtitle(paste0(mvar, " by ", gvar))
  )
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution despite my providing so many errors in my original post.  Could you help me understand -- why the as.formula() function inside the facet_grid() call works, and why the !!sgvar tidy_eval fails?

Comment: @HumanityFirst if you use the old formula interface you need to write the bare symbols in the formula (or you can create a formula from strings as in my example), but if you want to use tidy eval you could use the newer interface. `facet_grid(cols = vars(!!sym(gvar)))` would be the tidyeval version.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense -- thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I just [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767316/how-to-use-labeller-functions-to-get-column-totals-to-appear-in-the-label-of-a) the other day. I wonder how I could modify the `facet_grid()` call to incorporate the labeller() function and get the 'gvar' to evaluate correctly. Should I make a new post? or is it ok to ask in this comment?