# tidy_eval inside labeller() function for facet_grid() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I previously posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664629/tidy-eval-issue-with-facet-grid-in-ggplot2) as well as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767316/how-to-use-labeller-functions-to-get-column-totals-to-appear-in-the-label-of-a) which might give additional context to this question.

data for context:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)
dfr2 <- tibble(x1 = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:3]),
             x2 = factor(sample(letters[1:2], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:2]),
             x3 = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 50, replace = T), levels=letters[1:3]),
             grpA = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2")),
             grpB = factor(sample(c("grp1","grp2"),50, prob=c(0.6, 0.4) ,replace=T), levels = c("grp1", "grp2"))
             )

head(dfr2)
```

function for data prep in which I calculate variables used for plotting, as well as the group totals for the grouping variable: `grp_tot`

```
plot_data_prepr <- function(dat, groupvar, mainvar){
  
  groupvar <- sym(groupvar)
  mainvar <- sym(mainvar)
  
  plot_data <- dat %>% 
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>% 
    count(!!mainvar, .drop = F) %>% drop_na() %>% 
    mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         pct2 = ifelse(n == 0, 0.005, n/sum(n)),
         grp_tot = sum(n),
         pct_lab = paste0(format(pct*100, digits = 1),'%'),
         pct_pos = pct2 + .02)
  
  return(plot_data)
}
```

normal use of the data prep function:

```
plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr2, groupvar = "grpA", mainvar = "x1")
```

in the `labeller()` function below, I have to explicitly type `'grpA'` to get the code to work. Although this produces the desired result of facet labels with the appropriate labels, it is not what I want as it will prevent me from dynamically changing the grouping variable if I were to loop through grouping variables:

```
for(mvar in names(dfr2)[1:3]) {
  
  smvar <- sym(mvar)
  
  gvar <- names(dfr2[4])
  sgvar <- sym(gvar)
  
  dd <- plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr2, groupvar = gvar, mainvar = mvar)

  lookup <- unique(dd$grp_tot)

  plusN <- function(string) {
    
    label <- paste0(string, ' (N = ',lookup,')')
    label
  }
  
    plot <- ggplot(dd, 
                   aes(x = !!smvar,y = pct2, fill = !!smvar)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
      ylim(0,1) +
      geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar)), labeller = labeller(grpA = plusN))
      
    print(plot)
      
  }
```

Instead, I would like to be able to use the quoted symbol `gvar` so that I could dynamically change the grouping variable and labels atop the plot.  I tried changing the `plusN()` function by using `enquo()` on the `'string'` argument, and then changing `'grpA'` to `gvar` in the `labeller()` function, but now the facet labels do not appear at all:

```
for(mvar in names(dfr2)[1:3]) {
  
  smvar <- sym(mvar)
  
  gvar <- names(dfr2[4])
  sgvar <- sym(gvar)
  
  dd <- plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr2, groupvar = gvar, mainvar = mvar)

  lookup <- unique(dd$grp_tot)

  plusN <- function(string) {
    
    enquo(string)
    
    label <- paste0(!!string, ' (N = ',lookup,')')
    label
  }
  
    plot <- ggplot(dd, 
                   aes(x = !!smvar,y = pct2, fill = !!smvar)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
      ylim(0,1) +
      geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar)), labeller = labeller(gvar = plusN))
      
    print(plot)
      
  }
```

Perhaps someone might be able to help me resolve my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I get it, one approach to solve your issue would be to use a `labeller` function as `facet_grid` passes a df to the labeller function, where the column names of the df are the names of the facetting var(s). Try this:

Try this:

```r
for(mvar in names(dfr2)[1:1]) {
  
  smvar <- sym(mvar)
  
  gvar <- names(dfr2[4])
  sgvar <- sym(gvar)
  
  dd <- plot_data_prepr(dat = dfr2, groupvar = gvar, mainvar = mvar)
  
  lookup <- unique(dd$grp_tot)

  my_label <- function(x) {
    var <- names(x)[1]
    list(paste0(var, ": ", x[[var]], " (N = ", lookup, ")"))
  }
  
  plot <- ggplot(dd, 
                 aes(x = !!smvar,y = pct2, fill = !!smvar)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    ylim(0,1) +
    geom_text(aes(label=pct_lab, y = pct_pos + .02)) +
    facet_grid(as.formula(paste0(".~", gvar)), labeller = my_label)
  
  print(plot)
  
}
```

[image]